# Mediawiki refers to old domain after change

Tags: mediawiki

I changed the top level domain name of my mediawiki installation (wiki.olddomain.com -> wiki.newdomain.com). After editing the LocalConfig.php I can visit the wiki on the new domain, but after logging in or editing a page, I'm still referred to the old domain.

I suspect this is because I need to update something in the database, but ./php Update.php did not do the trick. Can somebody tell me what I need to update and how?

Answer (score 0):

A database dump revealed that the old domain name was in fact only in the externallinks and text tables.

The problems was that my mediawiki instance is in a docker container that appears to have to be restarted for LocalSettings.php to be re-read.